# PIL: What does the 'I' band in a TIFF file represent

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I have a TIFF image captured with a thermal camera. The image appears to be grayscale and does not have any visual colors.

When processing the image with PIL, the getbands() yields a single band of type 'I'. What does this 'I' band represent? I cannot find any documentation on it.

Furthermore, all of the pixel data revealed by the getdata() function has a value of approximately 22,000. I assume this is some sort of data encoding based on a number of bits, but it does not conform to normal RGB(A) value ranges.

Answer (score 0):

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html

here it says: I = (32-bit signed integer pixels)